# algorithm caption size reduction in book document

Tags: fontsize, algorithms

I need to reduce my caption size to scriptsize in my algorithm. I couldn't find a proper answer to this. Here's a M. W. E of my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{GenerateGraph(schema)}
\scriptsize
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
....
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Also is there a fix to reduce number size?( they seem bigger than text)I have annexed my algorithm below. Your help is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Why did you reduce the font size of the algorithm in the first place? Do you have more than just this algorithm in your document? If so, which font size do they use?

Comment: This algorithm uses whole page if I stick with default font size(i.e. 12pt) with very very less margin. So I had to reduce main text size. Now it looks odd with large caption. Now I want to reduce the caption size too. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was already a good answer to this question, it's not clear to me why it has been deleted... :-( However, since it has been deleted I'll try to answer it on my own:

With `caption` package the font size of the caption could be set with `\captionsetup{font=scriptsize}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\captionsetup{font=scriptsize} % set size of caption font
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}
\scriptsize                    % set size of algorithm itself
\begin{algorithmic}[1] % example taken from the algorithmicx documentation
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
  \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
  \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
    \State $a\gets b$
    \State $b\gets r$
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
  \EndWhile
  \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1] % example taken from the algorithmicx documentation
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
  \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
  \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
    \State $a\gets b$
    \State $b\gets r$
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
  \EndWhile
  \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

(Since `\captionsetup{font=scriptsize}` is applied inside the `algorithm`, it affects the current `algorithm` only.)

Without `caption` package the macro `\floatc@ruled` is used for typesetting the algorithm caption, so one could patch it to apply `\scriptsize` to the following algorithm (only):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\setalgorithmcaptionfont[1]{%
  \let\my@floatc@ruled\floatc@ruled          % save \floatc@ruled
  \def\floatc@ruled{%
    \global\let\floatc@ruled\my@floatc@ruled % restore \floatc@ruled
    #1\floatc@ruled}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setalgorithmcaptionfont{\scriptsize} % set size of next algorithm caption font
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}
\scriptsize                    % set size of algorithm itself
\begin{algorithmic}[1] % example taken from the algorithmicx documentation
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
  \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
  \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
    \State $a\gets b$
    \State $b\gets r$
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
  \EndWhile
  \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1] % example taken from the algorithmicx documentation
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
  \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
  \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
    \State $a\gets b$
    \State $b\gets r$
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
  \EndWhile
  \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped :)

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the solution without `caption` package one has to thank @frougon since without him I would not know that `\floatc@ruled` has to be patched for this purpose. (Unfortunately I haven't saved his code prior removal of his answer, so I had to write my own.)

Comment: Just curious to know. I did this with caption package. What is the advantage of using \floatc@ruled command without caption package?

Comment: AFAIK the `caption` package is not compatible to all document classes. If this affects you it's good to have an alternative solution.